# Apple iTunes & Family sharing: hide names of other members?

Tags: itunes, itunes-store, family-sharing, home-sharing

In my iCloud Apple ID I have family sharing enabled. I use it to share access to iTunes music with other AppleID holders (friends and family -- Apple offers 5 accounts to share with).

My problem is that every member can see other member's names: is there a way to disable/hide the names of those members from each other?

Comment: Tell us more about this "family" that can't know who the others are? I'm guessing the answer is no - you don't get to be private if you opt in to a "family" with shared payments, but let's see if there is that designed in in a proper answer of "no" or "yes"

Comment: Family can be anything... Unrelated friends for example..